# SSH for loop executing command script

Tags: php, bash, shell, ssh, scripting

I have a script to get server health from multiple servers like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip
do
    ssh 192.168.1.209 ssh root@$ip cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}' #CPU Usage
    free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}' #Memory Usage
    df -khP  | awk '{print $3 "/" $2}' | awk 'FNR == 2' #Disk Space
    df -kihP  | awk '{print $3 "/" $2}' | awk 'FNR == 2' #Inode Space
    date +'%d %b %Y %r %Z' #Datetime
    ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,args|sort -nr -k3|head -5 #Process
done
```

The 209 is acting like a portal on my network so I have to ssh to it 1st in order to access other servers. By typing this command on terminal:

```
./my_script.sh 192.168.1.210 192.168.1.211 192.168.1.212
```

I would like to get each of the command output (ps,date etc) from each server. Expected output for 2 servers should be like:

```
0.11 #health from server 1
4.82577
1.7G/49G
46K/49M
27 Dec 2016 05:34:57 PM HKT
root        93  0.0  0.0 [kauditd]
root         9  0.0  0.0 [rcuob/0]
root      8740  0.0  0.0 ifstat --scan=100
root       829  0.0  0.0 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -u -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log -P /var/run/wpa_supplicant.pid
0.00  #health from server 2
4.82422
1.7G/49G
46K/49M
27 Dec 2016 05:34:57 PM HKT
root        93  0.0  0.0 [kauditd]
root         9  0.0  0.0 [rcuob/0]
root      8740  0.0  0.0 ifstat --scan=100
root       829  0.0  0.0 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -u -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log -P /var/run/wpa_supplicant.pid
```

The problem that I'm facing is that It seems like it's only getting the health info from one server only. Why is that? Is it because I cannot do SSH like this? I'm using PHP exec() function to execute the script btw, to further format and display it on my local page.

Comment: oh i forgot to mention, the 209 is acting like a portal on my network. I can only ssh to 210,211 etc from 209. so Im actually ssh to 209 first

Comment: how do I do that? I have already given all of my code

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that in `bash` is to use [Here Documents `<<`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) and run a loop over each of the arguments (`$@`) passed to the script as

```
for ip in "$@"
do
    ssh 192.168.1.209 ssh root@"$ip" <<-EOF
    cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}'
    free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}' 
    df -khP  | awk '{print $3 "/" $2}' | awk 'FNR == 2'
    df -kihP  | awk '{print $3 "/" $2}' | awk 'FNR == 2'
    date +'%d %b %Y %r %Z'
    ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,args|sort -nr -k3|head -5
    EOF
done
```

Remember to **NOT** have leading or trailing whitespaces before header `<<-EOF` and the final `EOF`, use tab-space for the terminating `EOF`.

You can run the script now as

```
./my_script.sh 192.168.1.210 192.168.1.211 192.168.1.212
```

Also you can wrap the contents of the script in a simple `bash` script and run it in one shot as

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}'
free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}' 
df -khP  | awk '{print $3 "/" $2}' | awk 'FNR == 2'
df -kihP  | awk '{print $3 "/" $2}' | awk 'FNR == 2'
date +'%d %b %Y %r %Z'
ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,args|sort -nr -k3|head -5
```

Call the above script as `commandlist.sh` and call it inside the for-loop as

```
ssh 192.168.1.209 ssh root@"$ip" 'bash -s ' < /path-to/commandlist.sh
```

Comment: I am getting ./health.sh: line 14: warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./health.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: It is still the same, btw "<<-EOF" should be "<< EOF"?

Comment: @LimSY: Also for the terminating token `EOF` before `done`, do not use `<space>` character, use `<tab>` and can you try once?

Comment: Now it does not have any error, but without any output though. i have to press ctrl+c to cancel

Comment: @LimSY: Can you try the last suggestion from my answer? with the commands in a single file

Comment: same thing, does not have any output. also I try to do it without looping (hard code the $ip). it also does not have any output

Answer (score 0):

Well, I’d do something completely different.

First I’d write a `commandlist.sh` script as follows (not forgetting to make it executable...):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "# Health from $(hostname)"
cat /proc/loadavg | cut -d' ' -f1 #CPU Usage
free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}' #Memory Usage
df -khP  | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3 "/" $2}' #Disk Space
df -kihP  | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3 "/" $2}' #Inode Space
date +'%d %b %Y %r %Z' #Datetime
ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,args|sort -nr -k3|head -5 #Process
```

(mmh.. I would produce the same output with very different code, but since it’s your script I’ve only edited out a couple of superfluous `awk` invocations.)

Then, I’d place it on the 209, where I’d also install GNU `parallel`.
Separately, I’d write the file `~/.parallel/sshloginfile` as follows:

```
1/192.168.1.210
1/192.168.1.211
1/192.168.1.212
```

and I’d run the command

```
ssh 192.168.0.209 parallel -S .. --nonall --bf commandlist.sh ./commandlist.sh
```

Have a good look at `man parallel` for more possibilities.